# VBA elements not found in iframe

Tags: css, vba, selenium, web-scraping, iframe

am trying to get data using selenium on VBA. I want to click a radio box first to get to the desired page.

The following codes causes 'index outside of the bounds' error, because there's no elements that fits the condition (When I do `driver.FindElements(by.ID("DATAINI"))`, it displays 0).

```
Dim driver As New webdriver
    driver.Start "ie"
    driver.get fileLocation 'At this point, the website is properly opened.
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
    Dim by As New by
With driver
   .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByTag("iframe")
   .FindElements(by.ID("DATAINI"))(0).Click 
End With
```

However when I check the codes there are elements with the ID I specified. How can I solve this?
[image]

Comment: Hi. Did you try `FindElement`  ? Also, did you check you had switched to the correct iframe? Can you provide the url please? And can you not simply `driver.get` to the `src` value we see in the image above? Please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html we can copy paste, rather than an image. I also don't see that ID in the above image (but I have just woken up).

Comment: Thanks @QHarr, the url is below:

<bcb.gov.br/en/financialstability/quotations>

I tried driver.SwitchToFrame, which didn't work. I am not familiar with web scraping but I have to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the page has more than 1 `iframe`, so you certainly cannot use TagName to locate the right iframe.

Instead you can try with the below css :

```
driver.SwitchToFrame driver.FindElementByCss("iframe[src^='https://ptax.bcc.gov.br/ptax']")
```

and then you can interact with `DATAINI`, I do not see this in the above screen shot.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. There is no such element error at this code. Excuse me for my mistake but DATAINI does exist... I tried with other elements but none of them worked.

Comment: I believe we have to identify the right iframe, can you check in dev tools `iframe[src^='https://ptax.bcc.gov.br/ptax']` ? if it exists ?

Comment: I see! The source URL was different, so I modified it and was able to navigate to the iframe. I am still unable to access the element; I edited the picture in the question (I know that I should upload codes not pictures but I didn't get how to do that)

Comment: I still cannot see `DATAINI` in HTML

Comment: `input[id='DATAINI ']` , can you check in dev tools if we have unique entry  ?

Comment: is there any error ? when you try to click on it ? it's an input tag,  are you sure you want to click on it  ?

Comment: I just modified some variable names and it works now, thank you so much!